# Configure Apache Webserver to run Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

By default apache superset uses internal [webserver](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) . Although the installation manual says we can configure apache or nginx , I could not figure out how to do so. 
Can somebody tell me how to configure apache webserver to run superset ?

Answer (score 2):

using gunicorn to startup superset webapp, then using apache or nginx as the proxy to forward http request to it

```
/gunicorn -w 4 -k gevent --timeout 120 -b 127.0.0.1:6666 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0 superset:app
```

nginx conf as:

```
 location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: yeah but was looking to natively to run inside apache itself , figured out anyway that it needs WSGI interface to run any python/flask based application

Comment: @sashank Would you mind sharing what you did as an answer, I'm struggling with a similar problem

Comment: How to deploy superset on apache webserver using mod_wsgi?